# How to connect encrypted database in adobe air which its encryption key length is not 16 bytes?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I have an encrypted database and its encryption keys length is not 16 bytes. So when i am trying to connect this database i get this error down below :

```
 Error #3140: The encryption key size specified was not valid for this operation. Keys must be exactly 16 bytes in length.
```

Is there any way to connect this database? And why do i need an encryption key which is exact 16 bytes length to open?